# Number of ways to cover half of a grid by an orthogonally connected region

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Suppose that we have a grid of size $2n$ by $2n$, with $4n^2$ cells in total. How many ways are there to label each cell in the grid using two labels, say *zero* and *one*, such that all *ones* are orthogonally connected and exactly half of the grid contains *ones*?

For example, there are four ways to label the grid if $n=1$:

```
1 1 | 0 0 | 1 0 | 0 1
0 0 | 1 1 | 1 0 | 0 1
```

Brute force search suggests that there are $1474$ ways to label the grid when $n=2$, here are some examples:

```
1 1 1 1 | 0 0 1 1 | 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 | 0 0 1 1 | 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 1 | 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 1 | 1 1 0 0
```

To clarify, this is what I mean by "orthogonally connected". Let $A$ be a $2n$ by $2n$ matrix representing the grid, let $V = \lbrace (i, j) : A[i,j] = 1 \rbrace$ denote the positions of ones and let $E = \lbrace ((i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2)) \in V \times V: (i_1, j_1) \in \lbrace (i_2 + 1, j_2), (i_2 - 1, j_2), (i_2, j_2 + 1), (i_2, j_2 - 1) \rbrace \rbrace$. All ones are orthogonally connected whenever the graph $(V, E)$ is connected.

In the examples above, *ones* are orthogonally connected.

In the following examples, *ones* are not orthogonally connected.

```
1 0 0 1 | 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 | 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 | 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 | 1 1 1 1
```

For reference, here is the python code I used to compute the number 1474. It iterates over $2^{(4n^2)}$ possible ways to fill the grid, and uses `scipy.ndimage` to detect orthgonally connected components. In the problem, I only consider cases where `k` is even.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label

def count_solutions(k, print_patterns=False):
  count = 0
  k2 = k * k
  for i in range(2**k2):
    arr = np.array([int(x) for x in np.binary_repr(i).zfill(k2)]).reshape(k, k)
    if label(arr)[1] == 1 and arr.sum() == k2 // 2:
      if print_patterns: print(arr)
      count += 1
  return count
```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "orthogonally connected"?

Comment: I think it means all the 1s connected by the four orthogonal neighbors form a single connected component

Comment: The sequence $4,1474$ turns up nothing relevant at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which either means no one has looked at this problem yet, or $1474$ is wring.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I saw https://oeis.org/A065401 which may account for parity, although I did not think about what happens when `n` is odd. I calculated 1474 by considering all 2^16 possibilities and detecting connected components using a robust image processing library, so it is probably right unless I screwed something up.

Comment: For 3x3 grids, I find 36 distinct configurations if we choose four ones and 49 distinct configurations if we choose 5 ones.

Answer (score 2):

(Here I'm assuming an $n\times n$ grid rather than $2n\times 2n$, to more easily talk about odd-sized grids.)

I've written a program to compute a few more of these numbers (source code below). Using dynamic programming, it is possible to compute the answer in $O(n! 2^{n})$ time, which is a bit better than the $O(2^{n^2})$ naive enumeration. The basic idea is to work one row of the grid at a time: the possible states of each row can be encoded by (1) whether each entry of the row is a $0$ or a $1$; (2) one color for each of the $1$s, where two $1$s have the same color if they are connected by an orthogonal path of $1$s contained in rows $1\leq j \leq i$.

The number of valid ways to fill the grid is thus the number of ways to fill $j$ rows ($j \leq n$) with $n^2/2$ ones that all have the same color in the final row.

- $n=2$: $4$
- $n=4$: $1474$
- $n=6$: $71969832$
- $n=8$: $528144170884375$

I'm not seeing any patterns and the sequence is not in OEIS, so I'm rather pessimistic there's a nice closed form.

Here are some numbers for $n$ odd, if we requires $\lfloor n^2/2\rfloor$ ones:

- $n = 1$: $1$
- $n = 3$: $36$
- $n = 5$: $136217$
- $n = 7$: $78614780347$

### Source code:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct UnionFind
{
    UnionFind(int n)
    {
        parent.resize(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            parent[i] = i;
    }

    int find(int i)
    {
        int p = parent[i];
        if (parent[p] != p)
        {
            p = find(p);
            parent[i] = p;
        }
        return p;
    }

    void takeUnion(int a, int b)
    {
        parent[find(a)] = find(b);
    }

    std::vector<int> parent;
};

struct Row
{
    std::vector<int> groups;
    int64_t totalones;

    bool operator<(const Row& other) const
    {
        if (totalones < other.totalones)
            return true;
        if (totalones > other.totalones)
            return false;
        int n = groups.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (groups[i] < other.groups[i])
                return true;
            if (groups[i] > other.groups[i])
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Row buildTopRow(uint64_t top, int n)
{
    Row result;
    result.groups.resize(n);
    result.totalones = 0;
    bool prevset = false;
    int curgroup = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        bool curset = top & (1ULL << i);
        if(!curset)
        { 
            if (prevset)
            {
                curgroup++;
            }
            result.groups[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            result.groups[i] = curgroup;
            result.totalones++;
        }
        prevset = curset;
    }

    return result;
}

bool stitch(const Row& top, uint64_t bottom, Row &result)
{
    int n = top.groups.size();

    result.totalones = top.totalones;
    result.groups.resize(n);

    UnionFind uf(2*n);

    bool prevset = false;
    int curgroup = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        bool curset = bottom & (1ULL << i);
        if (!curset)
        {
            result.groups[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (prevset)
            {
                int nextgroup = top.groups[i];
                if (nextgroup != 0)
                {
                    uf.takeUnion(curgroup, nextgroup);
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                int nextgroup = top.groups[i];
                if (nextgroup != 0)
                {
                    curgroup = nextgroup;
                }
                else
                {
                    curgroup = n + i;
                }
            }

            result.groups[i] = curgroup;
            result.totalones++;
        }

        prevset = curset;
    }

    std::map<int, int> relabeling;
    int curidx = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (result.groups[i] != 0)
        {
            int canonical = uf.find(result.groups[i]);
            auto it = relabeling.find(canonical);
            if (it == relabeling.end())
            {
                relabeling[canonical] = curidx++;
            }
            result.groups[i] = relabeling[canonical];
        }
    }

    // check if we've irrecoverably disconnected the 1s

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (top.groups[i] != 0)
        {
            auto it = relabeling.find(uf.find(top.groups[i]));
            if (it == relabeling.end())
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void doCase(int n)
{
    std::map<Row, int64_t> ways;
    uint64_t options = (1ULL << n);
    for (uint64_t way = 0; way < options; way++)
    {
        ways[buildTopRow(way, n)] = 1;
    }

    int64_t answer = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < n - 1; row++)
    {
        std::map<Row, int64_t> nextways;
        for (auto& w : ways)
        {
            for (uint64_t way = 0; way < options; way++)
            {
                Row nextrow;
                if (stitch(w.first, way, nextrow))
                {
                    nextways[nextrow] += w.second;
                }
            }

            // are we done?
            if (w.first.totalones == n * n / 2)
            {
                bool ok = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (w.first.groups[i] > 1)
                        ok = false;
                }
                if (ok)
                {
                    answer += w.second;
                }
            }
        }    
        ways = nextways;
    }

    for (auto it : ways)
    {
        if (it.first.totalones != n * n / 2)
            continue;
        bool ok = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (it.first.groups[i] > 1)
                ok = false;
        }
        if (ok)
        {
            answer += it.second;
        }
    }
    std::cout << n << ": " << answer << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 62; i += 2)
    {
        doCase(i);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: just out of curiosity why use C ?

Comment: @SamaelManasseh No particular reason; it's just the language I'm most comfortable with.